# gitlab dosent restore backup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab

hello guys i use gitlab ce 12.0.6 & my Os is ubuntu 19.04
i create backup but when i want to import backups to the gitlab
i run this command

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1567495766_2019_09_03_12.0.6_gitlab_backup.tar
```

it shows me this error:

```
rake aborted!
 Permission denied @ dir_chdir - /home/ima/gitbackups/gitlab
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:114:in `chdir'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:114:in `unpack'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:restore
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

as a newbie i've searched everywhere but non of them don't work in my issue.
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pertinent portion of the error is:

```
Permission denied @ dir_chdir - /home/ima/gitbackups/gitlab
```

This directory should be owned by the user `git`. To change this, run `chown -R git:git /home/ima/gitbackups/gitlab`.

This also assumes that the directories above this have read/execute permission for all users. That is, if you run `ls -la /home/ima/gitbackups` and so on up the path, all should show something like `drwxr-xr-x`, where there is `r-x` at the end.